# How to load ms word document in jasper report

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports

How to load word document in the jasper report in java.

Comment: You need to say what you are trying to do (what you have said has too many interpretations).  Give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. Put the word document somewhere on a shared network drive and add a link to it in the report.
2. You can convert the word document to PDF and then link to that in your report. That way, almost anyone on the planet (not only Windows users) can read it.
3. You can convert the word document to PDF and then use a tool to convert that to PNG or JPEG images (one page = one image) and then include the images in your report. This will make the report very huge.
4. You can hope that Microsoft will implement a MS Word reader in Java and tell your boss in the meantime that it is not possible without some drawbacks.